# Inserindo dados em tabela sql server

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando inserir dados em uma tabela:

```
INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[observacaoProtocolos] (id_protocolo, statusObs1, observacao1, statusObs2, observacao2, statusObs3, observacao3, statusObs4, observacao4, statusObs5, observacao5, statusObs6, observacao6, statusObs7, observacao7, statusObs8, observacao8, statusObs9, observacao9, statusObs10, observacao10) 
VALUES (153,'OK','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')
```

Porém, o aparece um aviso:

> Não é possível inserir o valor NULL na coluna 'id_observacao', tabela 'RDO.dbo.observacaoProtocolos'; a coluna não permite nulos. Falha em INSERT.

Criei a tabela da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE observacaoProtocolos
(
    id_observacao int NOT NULL,
    id_protocolo int,
    statusObs1 varchar(4),
    observacao1 varchar(100),
    statusObs2 varchar(4),
    observacao2 varchar(100),
    statusObs3 varchar(4),
    observacao3 varchar(100),
    statusObs4 varchar(4),
    observacao4 varchar(100),
    statusObs5 varchar(4),
    observacao5 varchar(100),
    statusObs6 varchar(4),
    observacao6 varchar(100),
    statusObs7 varchar(4),
    observacao7 varchar(100),
    statusObs8 varchar(4),
    observacao8 varchar(100),
    statusObs9 varchar(4),
    observacao9 varchar(100),
    statusObs10 varchar(4),
    observacao10 varchar(100)
);
```

Comment: Acho que está muito errada essa modelagem. Por que você precisa ter 10 pares de campos status e observação?

Answer (score 2):

O erro está no seu *INSERT*.

Você nomeou os campos sendo inseridos, mas não incluiu o campo `id_observacao` que pela sua modelagem é `NOT NULL`.

Veja abaixo o correto:

```
INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[observacaoProtocolos] (
    id_observacao,
    id_protocolo, 
    statusObs1, 
    observacao1, 
    statusObs2, 
    observacao2, 
    statusObs3, 
    observacao3, 
    statusObs4, 
    observacao4, 
    statusObs5, 
    observacao5, 
    statusObs6, 
    observacao6, 
    statusObs7, 
    observacao7, 
    statusObs8, 
    observacao8, 
    statusObs9, 
    observacao9, 
    statusObs10, 
    observacao10) 
VALUES (0,
    153,
    'OK',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '')
```

Não sei qual Id seria correto para inserir, então coloquei 0.

Além disso, há diversos problemas na modelagem da sua tabela. Não existem chaves estrangeiras na declaração. O correto seria algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE observacaoProtocolos
(
    id_observacao_protocolo int primary key identity,
    id_observacao int NOT NULL,
    id_protocolo int NOT NULL,
    statusObs varchar(4),
    observacao varchar(100),
    constraint observacao_fk (id_observacao) references observacao (id_observacao),                 
    constraint protocolo_fk (id_protocolo) references protocolo (id_protocolo),
);
```

Ou seja:

- `id_observacao_protocolo` para identificar unicamente a associação;
- `id_protocolo` também passa a ser `NOT NULL` porque é chave estrangeira. Não faria sentido ser `NULL`;
- `statusObs` e `observacao` passam a ser uma coluna só. Não tem porquê ter esse par de campos 10 vezes;
- *Constraints* de chaves estrangeiras para evitar que sejam inseridos valores que não existem.